# Threejs blending modes doesn't work for 3 out of the 5 modes

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I am trying to use three.js blending and I have been trying to get `MultiplyBlending`, `SubtractiveBlending`, `NoBlending` to work but all that I get are white squares:

[image: White Squares Blending]

When I use `AdditiveBlending` I get something that works:

[image: Correct Blending]

fragment shader:

```c
uniform sampler2D diffuseTexture;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vAngle;

void main() {
  vec2 coords = (gl_PointCoord - 0.5) * mat2(vAngle.x, vAngle.y, -vAngle.y, vAngle.x) + 0.5;
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(diffuseTexture, coords) * vColor;
}
```

vertex shader:

```c
uniform float pointMultiplier;

attribute float size;
attribute float angle;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vAngle;

void main() {
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
  gl_PointSize = size * pointMultiplier / gl_Position.w;

  vAngle = vec2(cos(angle), sin(angle));
  vColor = color;
}
```

This is how I am creating the material and geometry in the TypeScript:

```js
    this.material = new Three.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        diffuseTexture: {
          value: new Three.TextureLoader().load(basicParticle)
        },
        pointMultiplier: {
          value: window.innerHeight / (2.0 * Math.tan(0.5 * 60.0 * Math.PI / 180.0))
        }
      },
      vertexShader,
      fragmentShader,
      blending: Three.MultiplyBlending,
      depthTest: true,
      depthWrite: false,
      transparent: true,
      vertexColors: true
    });

    this.geometry = new Three.BufferGeometry();
    new Three.Points(this.geometry, this.material);
```

What is causing me to get white squares and how can I fix it? Is it the shaders, TypeScript, or both?

Comment: I believe three.js has recently started taking the alpha channel into consideration when applying blending modes. So when using `Multiply` and `Subtract`, your alpha pushes towards 0 and your canvas will become transparent. You're seeing the `Additive` mode because in this case the alpha gets pushed towards 1.

Comment: @Marquizzo if that's the case what can I do? When looking at the examples they don't do anything except set transparent to true. Which is what I am doing as well...

Comment: Not sure, it depends on your use case. I ended up rendering a background cubemap, then rendering the multiplied points on top of that, but even that gave me odd results. See this discussion from 2 months ago: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/multiplyblending-is-affecting-my-canvas-alpha-channel/42094